# Vectors in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u,\,v,\,w$ be the vectors in an inner product space $V$, satisfying $\|u\|=\|v\|=\|w\|=2 $ and $\langle u,v\rangle=0,\langle u,w\rangle=1,\langle v,w\rangle=-1$.Then which of the following are true?

1)$w$ and $4u-w$ are orthogonal to each other.

2)$u,v,w $ are necessarily linearly independent.

I've got 1) as true since  $\langle w,4u-w\rangle=0$.But I don't know to solve 2).

Comment: For 2) if the answer is **no**, it's possible to find $x=\lambda_1u+\lambda_2v+\lambda_3w$ such that $<x,x>=0$

Comment: But it's [not possible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+4x%5E2%2B4y%5E2%2B4z%5E2%2B2xz-2yz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to find $a$ and $b$ such that $w = au + bv$. Taking an inner product with $u$ on both sides yields $1 = 4a$, so $a = 1/4$. Similarly, $b = -1/4$. So $w=(u - v)/4$. But the norm of this is not 2. Contradiction. So they are necessarily linearly independent!

Comment: excellent idea !!!

Answer (score 0):

The Gram determinant of the vectors $$\left|\begin{matrix}4&0&1\\ 0&4&-1\\ 1&-1&4\end{matrix}\right|$$ doesn't equal zero.

Comment: None of these vectors has norm $2$.

Comment: These have different norms and none of them has norm $2$. Besides, the first two are not orthogonal. What should this be a counterexample of?